# SDL Texture created from memory is rendering only in black and white

Tags: c, render, sdl-2

I am trying to port a game from DDraw to SDL2.

The original program loads the images and blits them to a backbuffer then flips it to a primary one.

I am thinking that I could technically shortcut part of the process and just grab the backbuffer in memory and then turn it into a texture and blit that to the screen. This kind of works already the only problem is that the screen is black and white.

here is some code. The variable that is holding the backbuffer is the destmemarea

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
    SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
}

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Texture *bitmapTex = NULL;
SDL_Surface *bitmapSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface *MySurface = NULL;

SDL_DisplayMode DM;
SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &DM);
auto Width = DM.w;
auto Height = DM.h;

window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial ", Width = DM.w - SCREEN_WIDTH, 32, SCREEN_WIDTH *4, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
if (window == NULL)
{
    printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
}

SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

int w, h;
SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(renderer, &w, &h);

SDL_Surface  * image =  SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(  destmemarea, 640, 0, 32, 640, 0, 0, 0,0);

SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

SDL_Delay(10000);
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

Not sure if this helps but this is what is being used for DDRAW fort he looks...

```
dd.dwWidth = 768;
dd.lPitch = 768;
dd.dwSize = 108;
dd.dwFlags = DDSD_PIXELFORMAT|DDSD_PITCH|DDSD_WIDTH|DDSD_HEIGHT|DDSD_CAPS;
dd.ddsCaps.dwCaps = DDSCAPS_SYSTEMMEMORY|DDSCAPS_OFFSCREENPLAIN;
dd.dwHeight = 656;
dd.ddpfPixelFormat.dwSize = 32;
```

Comment: What exactly is the part you want to short-cut? Double-buffering is automatically handled for you by SDL2, SDL_RenderCopy will draw to a backbuffer, and SDL_RenderPresent will swap the buffers.

Comment: Also your createRGBSurfaceFrom call looks super shaky:
SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(  destmemarea, 640, 0, 32, 640, 0, 0, 0,0);

Take a look at the documentation, it does not seem like you're passing proper parameters for it, most notably height and pitch:
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom

Comment: to the first comment. I need to ensure its copping to A  surface first. I will check the function out because I think you're right. I don't suppose you know of another way to render an image from memory using SDL?

Comment: Looking at the ddraw surface that is being created, this looks like a grayscale surface:
dwWidth = 768pixels, ddlPitch is 768 bytes, so that is 1 byte per pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I have a few assumptions.

You said that you're porting your codebase from DDraw, so I assume that the backbuffer you are mentioning is an internal backbuffer that you are allocating, and in the rest of your application are doing your rendering to it.

If I am correct in this assumption, than your current approach is what you need to do, but need to specify correct parameters to `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom`

- `width` and `height` are... width and height in pixels
- `depth` is the amount of **bits** in a single pixel. This depends on the rest of your rendering code that writes to your memory buffer. If we assume that you're doing a standard RGBA, where each channel is 8 bits, it would be 32.
- `pitch` is the size in **bytes** for a single row in your surface - should be equal to `width * (depth / 8)`.
- the 4 masks, `Rmask`, `Gmask`, `Bmask`, and `Amask` describe how each of your `depth` sized pixels distributes channels. Again, depends on how you render to your memory buffer, and the endianness of your target platform. From the documentation, 2 possible standard layouts:

  `#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN`

  ```
  rmask = 0xff000000;
  gmask = 0x00ff0000;
  bmask = 0x0000ff00;
  amask = 0x000000ff;
  ```

  `#else`

  ```
  rmask = 0x000000ff;
  gmask = 0x0000ff00;
  bmask = 0x00ff0000;
  amask = 0xff000000;
  ```

  `#endif`

Be sure not to forget to free your surface by calling `SDL_FreeSurface()`

With all that said... I think you are approaching your problem from the wrong angle. 
As I stated in my comment, SDL handles double buffering for you. Instead of having custom code that renders to a buffer in memory, and then trying to create a surface from that memory and rendering it to SDLs backbuffer, and calling present... you should skip the middle man and draw directly to SDLs back buffer.

This is done through the various SDL render functions, of which RenderCopy is a member.
Your render loop should basically do 3 things:

1. Call `SDL_RenderClear()`
2. Loop over every object that you want to present to the screen, and use one of the SDL render functions - in the most common case of an image, that would be `SDL_RenderCopy`. This would mean, throughout your codebase, load your images, create `SDL_Surface` and `SDL_Texture` for them, keep those, and on every frame call  `SDL_RenderCopy` or `SDL_RenderCopyEx`
3. Finally, you call SDL_RenderPresent exactly once per frame. This will swap the buffers, and present your image to screen.

Comment: You're right. I need to spend some time trying to figure out what is the issue with the pitch and masking.